# Grouping a Text File using Regular Expressions and Lists

Tags: c#, regex, list, file-io

So I have a file and I want to split it into 2 groups. Below I have a piece of code I have been working on:

```
string path = "TextFile";
string lines[] = File.ReadAllLines(path);
int count = lines.Length;
List<string> groupAlpha = lines.Take(7678).ToList();
List<string> groupBeta = lines.Skip(7678).Take(5292).ToList();
```

The numbers represent line numbers. My problem with this is that it uses line numbers to make them into groups. If I were to use different files in the future, it might not be seperated by those exact numbers. I do know though that each starts with:

```
***********BEGIN PROCESSING ALPHA PNRS***********
```

and ends with:

```
************END PROCESSING ALPHA PNRS************
```

Beta is the same as alpha, but BETA is inserted where ALPHA is.

My question is, is there a syntactical way where it is similar to what I have above, but uses regular expressions to solve my problem of making these into 2 groups of Lists? And if there is could you please let me know in the form of an answer instead of a comment? Thanks!

Comment: You can comment on your own question, i believe. A regular expression makes sence if the string to search in is not an array of lines. You could do it in code probably just as easy using the array tho. Are you saying you prefer a Regex solution?

Comment: @Fixation honestly, if you believe one way works better than the other then I would prefer the better method. I just thought initially when I saw my problem it would be solved using regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Linq is perfectly capable of this, using regular expressions makes it harder in my opinion.

```
string alphaStart = "***********BEGIN PROCESSING ALPHA PNRS***********";
string alphaEnd = "************END PROCESSING ALPHA PNRS************";
string betaStart = "***********BEGIN PROCESSING BETA PNRS***********";
string betaEnd = "************END PROCESSING BETA PNRS************";


List<string> groupAlpha = (lines.SkipWhile(s => s != alphaStart).Skip(1).TakeWhile(s => s != alphaEnd)).ToList();
List<string> groupBeta = (lines.SkipWhile(s => s != betaStart).Skip(1).TakeWhile(s => s != betaEnd)).ToList();
```

Comment: It looks fine, however when I change this out with the rest of my code, the whole program I am writing doesn't work anymore

Comment: What do the 1's mean in the .Skip?